# Cannot install the babel transpiler with npm

Tags: npm, babeljs

I am on a mac. I get the attached message when i try to run the command 
npm install babel:
...

npm WARN deprecated babel@6.23.0: In 6.x, the babel package has been deprecated in favor of babel-cli. Check https://opencollective.com/babel to support the Babel maintainers
/Users/samrao
└── babel@6.23.0

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/samrao/package.json'
npm WARN samrao No description
npm WARN samrao No repository field.
npm WARN samrao No README data
npm WARN samrao No license field.
Sams-MacBook-Air:~ samrao$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning states the node package module babel has been deprecated, I recommend having a look at this site for more information regarding babel and the documentation you can use to install it: [babeljs](https://babeljs.io).

The other errors that you get are because you are not using -g (Global) in the install command for npm so its trying to install the package in the local directory but cannot find package.json file.

Although on the babal installation page it states:

While you can install Babel CLI globally on your machine, it’s much better to install it locally project by project.

There are two primary reasons for this.

- Different projects on the same machine can depend on different
  versions of Babel allowing you to update one at a time.
- It means you do not have an implicit dependency on the environment
  you are working in. Making your project far more portable and easier
  to setup.

Comment: thanks - i got the latest download command from the website and ran it. but when i run the> babel filename.js command, it says Sams-MacBook-Air:~ samrao$ babel script.js
-bash: babel: command not found

Comment: does it mean that babel was not recognized?

Comment: @SamRao I was just to get it to work as expected what i did was run the command: 
npm install -g babel-cli. 

That made babel available everywhere, as the reason the error was happening to you was that the babel module could not be found.

Comment: @SamRao does this solve your problem? Can you mark it as the correct answer if it does.

Comment: Hi @HassanMahmud had to take a little break lol..  once I get back to my terminal I'll check and mark complete

Comment: Great :) @SamRao keep in mind if you have a particular project and you want to add node packages to it you can do something like npm init which create a new package.json and then you can choose to run dev or normal dependencies. If you plan to use a module everywhere you use the -g flag.

Comment: bingo! the following command worked npm install -g babel-cli.